# Can i change Google AdMob Ads's navigation bar position in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, admob

Can i change Google AdMob Ads's navigation bar position in ios?

[image: Can i change navigation bar position?]

and how to check google admob is on screen or not (dismiss) ?

Comment: do you want to resize the ad banner and want to give it origin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the admob is incorporated to your code as library and they haven't provided any API for moving this bar (a UIToolbar, not a UINavigationBar), you can't change it.

I **think** they don't have any property to check if the screen is being presented or not. But you can set a BOOL in your class, and set it to YES or NO in the GADBannerViewDelegate methods:

```
-(void)adViewWillPresentScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
-(void)adViewDidDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
-(void)adViewWillDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
-(void)adViewWillLeaveApplication:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
```

To understand it, you will need to read a little bit about delegation in Objective-c. But I will try:
In your class interface, you put:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <GADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    BOOL isPresentingBanner;
    GADBannerView *myBanner;
}
```

In your class implementation, after you init the delegate, define the delegate:

```
myBanner.delegate = self;
```

And you implement the delegate methods:

```
-(void)adViewWillPresentScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView
{
    NSLog(@"adViewWillPresentScreen");
    isPresentingBanner = YES;
}

-(void)adViewDidDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView
{
    NSLog(@"adViewDidDismissScreen");
    isPresentingBanner = NO;
}

-(void)adViewWillDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView
{
    NSLog(@"adViewWillDismissScreen");
}
```

Comment: Natan . thanks.. but its not working for me.. and can you explain how to set Bool variable in GADBannerViewDelegate?